# Is there any class generator for bltoolkit?

Tags: linq-to-sql, class, orm, generator, bltoolkit

Is there any class generator for bltoolkit?

Answer (score 1):

http://sogen.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

1. http://code.google.com/p/bltutilsvspackage/
2. http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Template/?id=a1e54825-1926-43aa-8b1f-1addbab63b30
3. BLToolkit supports the Linq2SQL attributes. So, Linq2SQL designer can be used.

Comment: 1. Cannot create even associations
2. Server Error